# I need help to show that some function is nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This is a function of $x\in(0,1]$ $$(a_0+v_0 )\left(a_1+\frac{1}{K}\right)\left(a_0+(1-x)  \frac{1}{K}\right)-(a_1+v_1 ) \left(a_0+\frac{1}{K}\right)(a_0+(1-x) v_0 )$$

The conditions are:
$a_0,a_1,K>0$ are constants, $v_0,v_1>0$ are functions of $x$.

Also $\frac{1}{K}-v_0>0$ and $ \frac{1}{K}-v_1>0$ for all $x$.

I just plot the funtion and it is alway nonegative, I'm not asking for the answer, you cant give it to me because you dont know how $v_0$ and $v_1$ 
dependent on $x$, I'm asking for tips to how can I prove that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused or wrong, but taking $K=a_1=1$, $a_0=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\nu_0=\nu_1=0$ (zero functions), this seems to become
$$
2a_0(1-x+a_0)-a_0(a_0+1) = a_0^2 + a_0(1-2x)
$$
which for $x=\frac{3}{4}$ becomes
$$
a_0^2 - \frac{1}{2}a_0 = a_0(a_0-\frac{1}{2}) = -\frac{1}{16} < 0
$$

Comment: sorry, $v_0,v_1$ can not be zero.

Comment: I still believe there may be some counterexample, though, even with this change. Take $a_0=\nu_0=\nu_1=\alpha > 0$, and $K=a_1=1$. Computing the expression (for fixed arbitrary $x >0$) and looking at the asymptotics when $\alpha \to 0$ may show the expression becomes negative.

Comment: The fact is that these values can not happen, because $v_0$ and $v_1$ depends on $x$, they are not arbitrary, I'm asking for tips for solve it.

Comment: But how can we give you tips if, given the information you gave, your statement *could be false*? The point is the assumptions you make (at least the ones you are willing to give us) *are* satisfied with this counterexample.

Comment: more information about is that $v_0',v_1'<0$

Answer (score 0):

Since all constants are positive real numbers, and v<sub>0</sub> and  v<sub>1</sub> are also strictly greater than 0, we can consider two cases. Either, 1) (1-x)>0 or 2) (1-x)=0. In the first case it is easy to see that the function must be greater than 0, since we are multiplying and adding positive numbers. For case number 2 the two terms with (1-x) must still be greater than 0, since (1-x) is always added to a<sub>0</sub> in some form or another.

Comment: They are not just adding, there is a minus.